# Converting Geometry to a Geography yields an invalid shape SQL SERVER

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server-spatial, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I have two Geometry shapes of types Polygon or MultiPolygon [with Lat & Lng points] that I want to get their intersected shape.
I do this as follows:

```
land_shape.STIntersection(grid_shape) as shape
```

Then, I check to see when

```
shape.STIsValid() = 1 and geography::STGeomFromText(shape.STAsText(), 4326).STIsValid() <> 1
```

and I get many results back. There are instances where the intersected shape as a geometry is valid, but as a geography isn't. This is an issue because I build on the geography shape to get the area.

I tested to see if converting both inputs `(land_shape & grid_shape)` to geography would also be invalid, but they are not invalid. So, inputs are not corrupt.

I'm not sure what could cause the intersected shape to be invalid as a geography.
I tried using `IsValidDetailed()` and the reasons were:

> ```
> 24409: Not valid because some portion of polygon ring (1) lies in the interior of a polygon.
> 24413: Not valid because of two overlapping edges in curve (1).
> ```

But, why were they valid as a geometry then? I know that `MakeValid()` can fix it, but I just need to understand why that behavior happens to begin with, and if I can eliminate this issue without using SQL Server's `MakeValid()` as I read it isn't entirely accurate.

Comment: Without the exact WKT, we can only guess, but great ellipse routes probably play a role.

Comment: @Vince would you say it's safe in this case to use 'MakeValid()' in case I want to get the intersection shape to calculate the area?

Comment: Actually using MakeValid() doesn't solve the issue of getting huge areas returned for shapes I know do not intersect.